# UpdatePanel in MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I'm using UpdatePanels in ContentPages sucefully, but now i'm trying to use one UpdatePanel in a MasterPage with an timer (i've setted the UpdateMode to conditional because the Timer) and i'm getting an problem: the update is refreshing the entire page (not like Ajax used in ContenPages).

It's because i'm using the UpdatePanel in the MasterPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Timer sits within the UpdatePanel and not outside it or surround the Timer with another UpdatePanel.  Also, you should check out the link medusa posted which covers some important points.

Comment: Thanks mate, it was outside the UpdatePanel ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting up any triggers to point to the timer?  Or where is the timer in relation to the update panel?